# ROS2 not found when doing docker exec

Tags: docker, exec, ros2

I am trying to run ROS2 in windows. But instead of installing it I did what is written [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html#run-two-nodes-in-a-single-docker-container)

Now running in one terminal works great.

My problem is when I want to access the container from other terminal

I do

```
docker exec -it <container name> ./bin/bash
```

Apparently I am inside the container but when I do

```
ros2 --version
```

I got

```
bash: ros2 command not found
```

it was running well on the first terminal why not in the second?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74124548/4451521) suggest to run `setup.bash` to source it, and I did. but this changes nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "docker exec" to run ros2 commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114225/using-docker-exec-to-run-ros2-commands)

Comment: As I **explicitly** wrote in the last line of my question, that does not answer my question.

Comment: "I did. but this changes nothing" is the opposite of compelling evidence.  After my considerable experience solving other people's problems, I have leanred not to take assumptions for granted.   I see no debugging information nor reproducible example that distinguishes your question from the duplicate.  You may not like the answer, but as it stands your question is still a duplicate, is it not?   If you disagree , provide additional information. There are numerous ways that "run setup.bash to source it" could be mis-executed; for starters; "running" and "sourcing" are critically different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple

run

```
source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
```